# How to test cmd-based programs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Helo,
I wrote some program that uses [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module. (The Cmd class provides a simple framework for writing line-oriented command interpreters.)

My program is cli to api.

My problem is that I can't test it now.

I can run:

```
# ./cli
   CLI Interface


    ------------
    Help may be requested at any point in a command by entering
    a question mark '?'.  If nothing matches, the help list will
    be empty and you must backup until entering a '?' shows the
    available options.
    Two styles of help are provided:
    1. Full help is available when you are ready to enter a
       command argument (e.g. 'show ?') and describes each possible
       argument.
    2. Partial help is provided when an abbreviated argument is entered
       and you want to know what arguments match the input
       (e.g. 'show pr?'.)

#role
Current Roles
rde:
   - base functionality
test:
   - Test
#quit
Exiting...
```

If I wrote test like:

```
from cli import Cli

class TestCliClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.cmdLine = Cli()
    def test_role(self):
        self.assertEqual("",self.cmdLine.do_role())
        #a=self.cmdLine.do_role()
        #print a
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It's output will be:

```
test_cli.py
-----------------------------
 current logs in /var/log/test_rdepyui.log
-----------------------------
Current Roles
rde:
   - base functionality
test:
   - Test
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_role (__main__.TestCliClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_cli.py", line 23, in test_role
    self.assertEqual("",self.cmdLine.do_role())
AssertionError: '' != None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.040s

FAILED (failures=1)

    import sys
    import os
    from cmd import Cmd
    USING_READLINE = True

    class Cli(Cmd,object):
    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        if not USING_READLINE:
            self.completekey = None
        self._hist=[]
        self.prompt = "#"
        self.intro  = """   CLI Interface """
    def default(self, line):
        cmd, arg, line = self.parseline(line)
        cmds = self.completenames(cmd)
        num_cmds = len(cmds)
        if num_cmds == 1:
            getattr(self, 'do_'+cmds[0])(arg)
        elif num_cmds > 1:
            sys.stdout.write('%% Ambiguous command:\t"%s"\n' % cmd)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('% Unrecognized command\n')
    def emptyline(self):
        pass

def do_role(self,args=None):
        try:            
            if args is None or args == 'show' or args.startswith('show') or args =='':
                roles = self.rderole.getRole()
                print "Current Roles"
                output=""
                #max_l=0
                for role in roles:

                    role_str="%s:" % (role)
                    output +=role_str+"\n"
                    #if len(role_str)>max_l:
                    #    max_l=len(role_str)
                    description=""
                    for subroles in roles[role]: 
                        print   subroles                 
                        if self.rderole.PLAYBOOK_DESCRIPTION in subroles:
                            description=subroles[self.rderole.PLAYBOOK_DESCRIPTION]
                            subrole_str="   - %s" % description
                            #if len(subrole_str)>max_l:
                            #    max_l=len(subrole_str)
                            output +=subrole_str+"\n"
                            #print subrole_str
                            #subrole_str.ljust(len(role_str))
                            #print subrole_str
                print output.strip()
            elif args == 'help' :
                Cmd.do_help(self, "role")
        except Exception as e:
            print "<ERROR>Can't show role: %s" % e
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        cmdLine = Cli()
        cmdLine.cmdloop()
```

Comment: Please add a little more explanation. What your program is expected to do?

Comment: You call it, and check that it prints what you expect

Comment: It's print not to the variable. I added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html) package:

```
import unittest 

from mymodule import Cli

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_cli(self):
       cli = Cli()
       cli.do_foofail()  # foofail must return something sensible which you can check with self.assertXXX() methods
```

Comment: Problem is that cli.do_foofail()  will return None. I added example

Comment: Fix your `do_foofail()` to return something testable

Comment: If function will return something cmd module stops flow.

Comment: Split your code to methods and functions so that you can call individual methods and functions in your test instead of a loop.

Comment: @ Mikko Ohtamaa I need test that after entering #role and role:#add something or #role add something All will work. I tested api classes. Now I need test that cmd is work. PS: There is onecmd() when run once https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cmd.py#l196 .

Comment: You can always call the your command as an external command using Python subprocess module and in the case you need to simulate the user command line input you can use pexpect: https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/